# Missing config.xml file in Visual Studio - Cordova Project

Tags: android, xml, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have just started using the Cordova's development tools, I wanted to improve my " test app " by adding a splash screen, but I don't know how to do, while I was surfing the net I found that change to splashcreen and icon need to be done in the config.xml file, but I don't have this file in my project folders.
How can i do ? ( I'm programming on Android platform )

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Visual Studio Apache Cordova tools? You'll know you're using them if the project in your solution explorer says (Apache Cordova) in the name.

I'm surprised that `config.xml` isn't already in your project, but you can grab a copy of it from the following sample project:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples/tree/master/todo-angularjs/AngularJSTodoApp

Comment: Yes, in the name there is ( tools for Apache Cordova ) and there is a config.xml file, but when I open it there is a menu composed by: Platforms, Plug-in, Windows ... I'm a beginner and so I don't know what this file is about. In addition in which folder should I create the config.xml file ? Thank you for all assistance.

Comment: This file should be at the root of your project, next to `www`, `merges`, etc. To help you get familiar with the project structure, I suggest reading through the following article: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/

Comment: The article seems clear, I'll read it. If I have problems I'll contact you. Thank you so much !

Comment: When you right click on the config.xml file on solution explorer, you'll get a dialog box that gives you the option to view the code in the config.xml file.  If you just double click on the config.xml file, you get the menu you describe above.  When you view the code you can edit the config.xml file for platform parameters, preferences, etc.